# Tableau SDK TableException (40200)

Tags: python, tableau-api

Issue: Error being thrown: tableausdk.Exceptions.TableauException: TableauException (40200): The system cannot find the path specified.
- OS::mkdir(CreateDirectory path="C:\PATH\Tableau-SDK\tdetmp2A0E0E5E")

I am attempting to to create a tableau extract from oracle data using python and the tableauSDK.

The code seems to run correctly if the extract already exists. (although the produced tde is unreadable)

According to the Tableau community I should be able to create an extract from any source data without the extract already existing...

Any idea on why this is occuring?

```
tde_path = r'C:\PATH\test.tde'
tde_file = Extract(path=tde_path) ## ERROR Thrown here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason now seems obvious...
The error had the answer :
OS::mkdir(CreateDirectory path="C:\PATH\Tableau-SDK\tdetmp2A0E0E5E")

To solve the issue :

The Directory C:\PATH\Tableau-SDK\ did not exist.
Created the Directory and the code ran without error.